# Trying to add a database reference to a database that references another database getting "no such source" error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

We have three databases, `Basic, Standard, Advanced`. We have the `Standard` database referencing the `Basic` database, and that all works fine.

Now we are implementing the `Advanced` database and I'd expect that we'd only need to reference the `Standard` db and it would automatically become a 'grandchild' of the `Basic` database.

When I try that I get errors on build:

> The reference to external elements from the source named 'Basic.Database.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded.

Has anyone tried this before?

[image: Database Reference Properties]

Comment: Do you mean you are using "Database References"? Which type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a reference to the Basic database in the Advanced database.  Basically, you can nest as many levels as you want, but you must have a reference to all of the DACPACs of the lower level for it to work.